# How to create a Geomap using values in databases such as SQL

Tags: reactjs, flask, chart.js, geomap

I want to create a geomap using chart.js and extract the values from SQL.Please help me to do the same

I tried to do it using static values in vscode.Can it be done using any of the python libraries or Flask/Django or do I need to use jquery?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.